# Implementation of a Hash Map in C++

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

I created a templated Hash Map class in C++, which supports most of the basic C++ types (e.g. `int`, `float`, `char`...). I would like some feedback regarding my implementation and what is bad and can be improved.

```
#ifndef _LIB_HASHMAP
#define _LIB_HASHMAP
#include <exception>
#include <string>

namespace lib{

    namespace details{

        unsigned int generate_hash(const int& key, const size_t& hash_map_size){
            return key%hash_map_size;
        }

        unsigned int generate_hash(const std::string& key, const size_t& hash_map_size){
            return key.size()%hash_map_size;
        }

        unsigned int generate_hash(const char* key, const size_t& hash_map_size){
            size_t position = 0;
            for (size_t i=0; key[i]!='\0'; i++){
                position += key[i];
            }
            return position%hash_map_size;
        }

    }


    template <typename T, typename U>
    class hash_map{

    private:
        struct hash_entry{
            T key;
            U value;
            hash_entry(){}
            hash_entry(const T& _key, const U& _value)
                : key(_key), value(_value){}
        };
        hash_entry* hash_entries;
        unsigned int* filled_positions;
        unsigned int hash_map_size;
        unsigned int num_entries;

    public:
        typedef const hash_entry* const_iterator;
        typedef hash_entry* iterator;
        explicit hash_map(unsigned int);
        ~hash_map();
        iterator begin();
        iterator end();
        const_iterator cbegin();
        const_iterator cend();
        unsigned int size();
        void add(const T&, const U&);
        U& operator[](const T&);
    };

    template <typename T, typename U>
    hash_map<T,U>::hash_map(unsigned int _size):
        hash_entries(new hash_entry[_size]),
        filled_positions(new unsigned int[_size]()),
        hash_map_size(_size),
        num_entries(0){
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    hash_map<T,U>::~hash_map(){
        delete[] filled_positions;
        delete[] hash_entries;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    typename hash_map<T,U>::const_iterator hash_map<T,U>::cbegin(){
        return hash_entries;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    typename hash_map<T,U>::const_iterator hash_map<T,U>::cend(){
        return hash_entries+hash_map_size;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    typename hash_map<T,U>::iterator hash_map<T,U>::begin(){
        return hash_entries;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    typename hash_map<T,U>::iterator hash_map<T,U>::end(){
        return hash_entries+hash_map_size;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    unsigned int hash_map<T,U>::size(){
        return hash_map_size;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    void hash_map<T,U>::add(const T& _key, const U& _value){
        if (num_entries >= hash_map_size){
            throw std::out_of_range("std::out_of_range : hash_map full");
        }
        unsigned int position = details::generate_hash(_key,hash_map_size);
        while (filled_positions[position]){
            position = (position+1)%hash_map_size;
        }
        filled_positions[position] = 1;
        hash_entries[position] = hash_entry(_key,_value);
        num_entries += 1;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    U& hash_map<T,U>::operator[](const T& _key){
        unsigned int position = details::generate_hash(_key,hash_map_size);
        unsigned int count = 0;
        while (hash_entries[position].key != _key){
            if (count > hash_map_size){
                throw std::invalid_argument("std::invalid_argument : key not in hash_map");
            }
            position = (position+1)%hash_map_size;
            count += 1;
        }
        return hash_entries[position].value;
    }

}

#endif // _LIB_HASHMAP
```

Comment: Why `T` and `U` instead of `K` for key and `V` for value?

Comment: For better flexibility, the hashing function to use could be a template parameter too, so that the user can use any type he wants for key, as long as he also provides a hashing function.

Comment: Of course, the user-provided hashing function would return an arbitrary `int` and the `%hash_map_size`  would be done in your class on the returned value.

Comment: In your 'default' hashing functions, why is `char*` hashed based on its content while `std::string` is hashed only based on its size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the description claims that most C++ types are supported, I see only `int` and two kinds of string.  The `std::hash` class [is specialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Standard_specializations_for_basic_types) for quite a few more types than that:

```
template<> struct hash<bool>;
template<> struct hash<char>;
template<> struct hash<signed char>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned char>;
template<> struct hash<char16_t>;
template<> struct hash<char32_t>;
template<> struct hash<wchar_t>;
template<> struct hash<short>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned short>;
template<> struct hash<int>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned int>;
template<> struct hash<long>;
template<> struct hash<long long>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned long>;
template<> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
template<> struct hash<float>;
template<> struct hash<double>;
template<> struct hash<long double>;
template< class T > struct hash<T*>;
```

In addition, the `std::string` hash is very collision-prone, as it uses only the length of the string (and the `char*` version doesn't even use `std::strlen()` - are you intending to even reinvent that wheel?).

---

`std::size_t` is missing its necessary include (usually `<cstdlib>`) and is consistently misspelt.

We need to include `<stdexcept>` for `std::out_of_range` and `std::invalid_argument`.

---

The compiler-generated copy constructor won't do what we want with `hash_entries` or `filled_positions` - that's dangerous, and will lead to multiple objects believing they own the pointers, and double deletion.

---

`cbegin()` and `cend()` functions ought to be usable on a `const hash_map` (and `begin()` and `end()` ought to be overloaded suitably, too).  Other const methods are lacking (such as `find()`) which make const maps much less useful than they ought to be.

Comment: You can also add that `size()` should be `const` and that a `const` version of `operator[]` could be provided (plus a way to remove entries). If c++17 is an option, `std::string_view` could be considers as parameter type for key.